# Red-Letter King James Version: Who is speaking in Revelation 21:5–6?

Tags: revelation

Who is speaking in Revelation 21:5–6? From what I understand, the words of Jesus Christ are printed in red. It appears that Jesus may be speaking in these two verses.

Revelation 21:5–6

> <sup>5</sup> And he that sat upon the throne said, Behold, I make all things new. And he said unto me, Write: for these words are true and faithful. <sup>6</sup> And he said unto me, It is done. I am Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the end. I will give unto him that is athirst of the fountain of the water of life freely. <sup>KJV, ©1769</sup>

Answer (score 1):

#### Red-Letter (Rubricated) Edition Bibles

Louis “Klopsch published the first modern red letter edition New Testament later in 1899. The first modern, fully rubricated bible was published in 1901.”<sup>1</sup> According to Wikipedia,<sup>2</sup>

> Because the original texts of the Sacred Scriptures do not have quotation marks, **which words exactly are Dominical has been interpreted**, as opposed to explanatory text that follows them.

While some red-letter edition bibles have Rev. 21:5–6 rubricated, others do not. In fact, [Klopsch’s own edition](http://1901kjv.com/klopsch-0644.html) published in 1901 did not have these verses rubricated:

[image: Louis Klopsch Red Letter Bible, Rev. 21:5–6]

#### Book of Revelation

In the Book of Revelation, the author consistently refers to God the Father as “He who sits on the throne.”<sup>3</sup> The living creatures give thanks to “Him who sits on the throne.”<sup>4</sup> John sees a book in the right hand of “Him who sits on the throne.”<sup>5</sup> He then sees the Lord Jesus Christ—“the Lion of the tribe of Judah, the Root of David”—come to open the book.<sup>6</sup> Then, “he came and took the book out of the right hand of Him who sits upon the throne.”<sup>7</sup> In Rev. 5:13, “Him who sits upon the throne” is distinguished from “the Lamb.”<sup>8</sup>

> <sup>13</sup> And every creature which is in heaven, and on the earth, and under the earth, and such as are in the sea, and all that are in them, heard I saying, Blessing, and honour, and glory, and power, be unto **him that sitteth upon the throne**, **and** unto **the Lamb** for ever and ever. <sup>KJV, ©1769</sup>

It is likely that Rev. 21:5–6 is spoken by God the Father since the author mentions “the Lamb” elsewhere in the chapter,<sup>9</sup> and the author continues to distinguish between God the Father and the Lamb.<sup>10</sup> One verse later in Rev. 21:7, the subject (speaker) states, “He who overcomes shall inherit all things, and I will be his God, and he shall be my son.”

---

#### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> Wikipedia entry “[Red letter edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_letter_edition)”
<sup>2</sup> *ibid.*
<sup>3</sup> Rev. 4:9–10, 5:1, 5:7 cf. Dan. 7:9
<sup>4</sup> Rev. 4:9
<sup>5</sup> Rev. 5:1
<sup>6</sup> Rev. 5:5
<sup>7</sup> Rev. 5:7
<sup>8</sup> cf. Rev. 6:16, 7:10
<sup>9</sup> Rev. 21:9, 21:14, 21:27
<sup>10</sup> Rev. 21:22–23

#### References

[*The Holy Bible Red Letter Edition Containing the Old and New Testaments.*](http://1901kjv.com/klopsch-0001.html) Ed. Klopsch, Louis. New York: World Syndicate Comnpany, 1901.

Answer (score 1):

**Red-Letter King James Version: Who is speaking in Revelation 21:5–6?**

Revelation 21:6-7  (NET Bible)

> 6 "He also said to me, “It is done! I am the Alpha and the Omega, the
>   beginning and the end. To the one who is thirsty I will give water
>   free of charge from the spring of the water of life."

It is God speaking, this is identified when the speaker says in the following  verse **7 : " The one who conquers will inherit these things, and I will be his God and he will be my son."**

**Jesus** referred to his faithful followers and joint heirs as his **"brothers." and not "sons,"** therefore it is God the Father, who is referring to himself as the "Alpha and the Omega."

Matthew 25:40  (NET Bible)

> 40 "And the king will answer them, ‘I tell you the truth, just as you
>   did it for one of the **least of these brothers or sisters of mine,** you
>   did it for me.’

Hebrews 2:10-12  (NET Bible)

> 10 "For it was fitting for him, for whom and through whom all things
>   exist, in bringing many sons to glory, to make the pioneer of their
>   salvation perfect through sufferings. 11 For indeed he who makes holy
>   and those being made holy all have the same origin, and so he is not
>   ashamed to call them brothers and sisters, 12 saying, “**I will
>   proclaim your name to my brothers;** in the midst of the assembly I
>   will praise you.”

Conclusion .

The expression **"Alpha and Omega  the beginning and the end "** is spoken by God the Father of  Jesus and carries the same idea as Isaiah 44:6 which states:   " Thus saith Jehovah, the King of Israel, and his Redeemer, Jehovah of hosts: **I am the first, and I am the last; and besides me there is no God."  (ASV)**

Answer (score 0):

Agree that it is God speaking, God the majestic.  And for this additional reason; that we know:
1cor.15:28 When all things are subjected to Him, then the Son Himself also will be subjected to the One who subjected all things to Him, so that God may be all in all.
And in Rev.21:5, we have reached that point, where it is God sitting on the throne. The implication of this is that Christ is not God.  He is one with God, and so may we be, according to the Gospel of godliness.  Too many today say Christ is God.  He is the Christ, the one whom is prophesied of, and duly fulfills those prophesies, right up to the point that it wasn't, by a day, yet His time, then, when that time came and He had given Himself for our salvation, he announced "It is DOne."  He is our Saviour, isn't that enough?

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).